# LongpressGesture end won't dismiss view

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I created `LongPressGestureRecognizer` which should open popup and on release `dismiss` it. However it doesn't `dismiss` it for some reason. What could cause this?

I do it like this:

```
func longPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let brandInfoVC = BrandInfoViewController(nibName: "BrandInfo", bundle: nil)


        // Create the dialog
        let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: brandInfoVC, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)

        if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {

            let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                print("LongPressed cell", brands[indexPath.row])

                // Present dialog
                self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }else if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended{
            print("LongPress released")//It does this
            popup.dismiss()// But it doesn't do this
        }

    }
```

Comment: @matt Sadly it didn't make any difference. The PopupDialog is simply third party [library](https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog) to display popups easily.

However I tried even without the PopupDialog library, just loaded xib and tried `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` which didn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. There must be something else going on that you have not described. As a very simple test, I implemented this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func longPress(_ sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            let vc = UIViewController()
            vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            vc.transitioningDelegate = self
            self.present(vc, animated:true)
        case .ended:
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        default:break
        }
    }
}

class MyPresentationController : UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 60, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

extension ViewController : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, 
        presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) 
        -> UIPresentationController? {
            return MyPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, 
                                            presenting: presenting)
    }
}
```

And this is what I get when I hold down on the view to which the long press gesture recognizer is attached, and then when I release:

[image]

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is working very well. I do not know what kind of dismiss it was there :)